# C# - Could sending 5 Multicast UDP packets result in 3 or more being lost

Tags: c#, sockets, networking, network-programming, udp

Good Day All

Is it possible sending multicast packet(s) over a LAN result in some or at least 50% of the packets being lost.

My application makes use of Multicast packets, when sending these packets, at times I only receive 1, other times 2. Only 2 times I received all the packets I sent.

Here are tests I did to see which packets are returned/received. 5 packets were sent, not all are returned (F - Final packet in sequence of packets sent)

2000 Random chars were used for these tests.

> 12345
> 14F
>
> 12345
> 134F
>
> 12345
> 1F
>
> 12345
> 1
>
> 12345
> 1
>
> 12345
> 1F
>
> 12345
> 134F

I always recieve atleast 1 packet. I understand Multicast = UDP, but it does not seem normal to lose so many packets.

**sending multicast packets:**

```
        Socket _listener_socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
        foreach (IPAddress localIP in Dns.GetHostAddresses(Dns.GetHostName()).Where(i => i.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork))
        {                
            _listener_socket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.IP, SocketOptionName.AddMembership, new MulticastOption(_MultiIP, localIP));
            _listener_socket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.IP, SocketOptionName.MulticastTimeToLive, 1);
            _listener_socket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);
            _listener_socket.MulticastLoopback = true;
            _listener_socket.Connect(new IPEndPoint(_MultiIP, _PORT));
            int count = MSGS_TO_SEND.Count;
            while (count > 0)
            {                    
                count--;
                byte[] temp = (byte[])(MSGS_TO_SEND.Dequeue());
                _listener_socket.Send(temp, _BYTE_BUFFER_SIZE, SocketFlags.None);
                MSGS_TO_SEND.Enqueue(temp);
            }
        }
        _listener_socket.Close();
```

**and recieving:**

```
        Socket _sender_socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
        IPEndPoint ipep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, _PORT);
        _sender_socket.Bind(ipep);
        IPAddress localip = _MultiIP;
        _sender_socket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.IP, SocketOptionName.AddMembership, new MulticastOption(localip, IPAddress.Any));
        Q_RECIEVE = new Queue<char[]>();
        while (_sender_socket.IsBound && !bStop)
        {
            byte[] b = new byte[_BYTE_BUFFER_SIZE];
            _sender_socket.Receive(b);
            char[] chars = new char[_BYTE_BUFFER_SIZE];
            System.Buffer.BlockCopy(b, 0, chars, 0, b.Length);
            Q_RECIEVE.Enqueue(chars);
        }
```

**UPDATE**

**Some interesting results - Kudo's to Seth for his suggestions**

After testing the firewall suggestion, I received some improvement but still having packet loss:

I disabled my Kaspersky firewall, defauting back to Windows 10 Defender Firewall:

> 12345
> 234F
>
> 12345
> 234F
>
> 12345
> 1234F
>
> 12345
> 1F
>
> 12345
> 14F
>
> 12345
> 234F
>
> 12345
> 1
>
> 12345
> 1
>
> 12345
> 234F

With Kaspersky Firewall disabled, I changed the byte[] size from 1024 to 512 thus only sending 256 char's per packet (and thread sleep time of 20ms), results improved drastically:

> 123456789
> 2345678F
>
> 123456789
> 2345678F
>
> 123456789
> 2345678F
>
> 123456789
> 2345678F
>
> 123456789
> 2345678F

Only my first packet was being dropped, but this is quite an improvement!

Comment: Environmental factors can cause UDP packet loss, such as low RSSI (low SNR).

Comment: Yes, it is possible, though not very likely, maybe there is some programmer's error involved.

Comment: @tinky_winky care to elaborate, programmer's error - does this refer to an error in my code, since this is adapted from a multicast tutorial :p but this programmer's error in gerneral, I assume this also refers to massive applications sending 1000's of udp packets, in my case, 3 of 5 packets do not return...this doesn't seem normal

Comment: I would really like to help you mate, but the technology has changed to C# which I don't know much about thankfully.

Comment: @tinky_winky my apologies for any misunderstanding, I think I need to change a tag or so. This is C# I am refering and coding in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, any time you are sending UDP there are a variety of factors which can cause packets to be lost, even on a LAN.  Here are a few that seem relevant:

- 2000 bytes is larger than the typical LAN MTU of 1500 (less headers).  That means the datagram will be fragmented.  If any fragment is lost, the entire datagram is lost, and some firewalls will block fragments if they arrive in certain patterns.
- UDP itself has no flow control.  If you send too much data, too quickly, packets will be dropped.  It sounds like you are only sending a few datagrams at a time, but check your UDP send and receive buffers.  If either is only big enough to hold one or two datagrams, then the rest may be dropped.
- Firewalls sometimes treat UDP strangely.  DoS prevention, deep packet inspection, tunnel blocking, and a bunch of security sounding buzzwords mean the firewall making a wild guess about the purpose of a datagram.  If the firewall guesses incorrectly, some of your datagrams may be dropped.
- It looks like you are setting TTL to 1.  In theory, that's correct for a LAN.  But if the local routing is a bit off, that could cause some packets to be dropped.

So, reduce your payload to 1400 bytes, make sure your UDP send and receive buffers are at least 64 kilobytes (preferably a megabyte, there's no reason to be stingy), disable any firewalls, and test with a larger TTL.

If any of that fixes the problem, you can dig in to find the exact cause.

Comment: @SethNoble thanks for the indepth info. 1. My byte[] buffer is length 1024B or 1 Kb.(string length = 512 * sizeof(char) = 1024). 2. I tried sleeping the "send thread" for 20ms, did not help. 3. Firewall - SEE UPDATE. 4. I have a single home router which I do the testing on, I tried TTl of 2, Wireshark reported malformed packets

Comment: That should be slow enough and small enough by far.  Try testing with unicast: it may be that something in your network is handling multicast differently.  Some firewalls and devices really throttle it.  Check whether your switches are rated for multicast.  You can also try unicast to the broadcast address of your LAN subnet.  For example, 192.168.255.255.